# Converting file formats (genetic datasets) from csv files to other formats (Arlequin)?

Tags: python, csv, converters

I would like to convert my .csv file (SNP dataset) using either Python or bash, but I am a 100% beginner in this. I spent the whole day trying to understand and look for python script but every time I type something using pandas there is a mistake somewhere. Can Anyone help?

Cheers

Comment: Please, post  some testable sample data with related expected output and a mentioned failed trial.

Comment: Do you mean reading csv file using python or convert csv file to some other format?

Comment: Can't you use Python to convert files into formats that are not python formats? I think you can. I just do not know what the script should look like. Or if there is some packages (not python, either R or bash) that can do this for me.